# How to get expiration time for a key on Redis using Dotnet Core?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm following [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.distributed.distributedcacheextensions.getstring) to implement Redis cache on Dotnet Core.

Unfortunately t seems that both Get(key) and GetString(key) only return the value, not the metadata such as expiry.

When I use redis-cli I'm able to retrieve both the data and metadata using `HGETALL key`

```
1) "absexp"
2) "637153531959962660"
3) "data"
4) "[{<snip>}]"
5) "sldexp"
6) "-1"
```

Is there any way to access this metadata from my code?

There might of course be workarounds like adding the expiry in the data object itself or adding a second key that contains the metadata, but neither solutions are very elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.

There is no way to get this from reviewing [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.stackexchangeredis.rediscache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and source.

You will have to get it using StackExchange.Redis directly.

Follow the same approach used on [RedisCache.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis/RedisCache.cs):

```
//RedisCacheOptions options as passed to RedisCache contructor.
ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options.ConfigurationOptions);
IDatabase cache = connection.GetDatabase();
HashEntry[] results = cache.HashGetAll(key);
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I went for wrapper around the object in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the KeyExpireTimeAsync method from the StackExchange.Redis library to get the expiration time of a Redis key asynchronously.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).